# Как получить только ссылки из HTML?

Tags: php, html, регулярные-выражения

Есть два блока:

```
<article class='vip'><span><a href=''>ссылка1</a><span></article>

<article><span><a href=''>ссылка2</a></span></article>
<article><span><a href=''>ссылка3</a></span></article>
```

Как мне получить только ссылки, без класса `class='vip'` ?

Comment: Не нужно парсить html при помощи регулярных выражений. Для этого есть специальные инструменты, при помощи которых задача решается довольно просто.

Ну и, традиционно, [канонический ответ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: У ссылок тут нет класса vip ;)

Comment: http://ideone.com/a3ldK6

Comment: А что вы хотите получить в итоге, только теги <a> и всё что в них? Можете добавить в вопрос?

Answer (score 1):

https://regex101.com/r/qO1bE8/2
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c76aed1ffa09d26bbbed41aea00de674ebc3fa15

```
<?php

$html = "<article class='vip'><span><a href='http://mail.ru'>ссылка1</a><span></article>

<article class='link'><span><a href='http://google.com'>ссылка2</a></span></article>
<article><span><a href='http://ya.ru'>ссылка3</a></span></article>";

preg_match_all("/<article(?(?!vip).)*><span><a href='(?<url>[^']*)'>(?<text>[^<]*)<\/a><\/span><\/article>/", $html, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <article class='link'><span><a href='http://google.com'>ссылка2</a></span></article>
            [1] => <article><span><a href='http://ya.ru'>ссылка3</a></span></article>
        )

    [url] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://google.com
            [1] => http://ya.ru
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://google.com
            [1] => http://ya.ru
        )

    [text] => Array
        (
            [0] => ссылка2
            [1] => ссылка3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => ссылка2
            [1] => ссылка3
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
<?php
$str = "<article class='vip'><span><a href=''>ссылка1</a><span></article>
<article><span><a href=''>ссылка2</a></span></article>
<article><span><a href=''>ссылка3</a></span></article>";
$pattern = "/<article>\s*<span>\s*(<a[^>]+>[^<]+<\/a>)/is";
preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $out);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($out[1]);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
$html =<<<HTML
<article class="vip">
    <span><a href="">ссылка1</a><span>
</article>

<article>
    <span><a href="">ссылка2</a></span>
</article>

<article>
    <span><a href="">ссылка3</a></span>
</article>
HTML;

$regexp = "<a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>";
if (preg_match_all("/$regexp/siU", $html, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches[0]);
}
```